# How to send conflicts after merges to developer

Tags: svn, mercurial

We have a release manager making many branches merging to release branch and sometime there're  logical merge conflicts and only developers can decide how to merge right. 
Is there good way(svn, mercurial - doesn't matter) how to send to developers these conflicts and then return fixed files to release manager except ask them to make real svn/hg merge.

Answer (score 2):

Usually one makes the developers merge in their changes and then push the the release manager pulls from the developer's already merged repo.

Merging ***is*** coding, and while I'm sure your release manager is perfectly capable of merging in branches, try to build a workflow where when the feature done the developer does:

1. hg pull release-candidate-repo
2. hg merge   # their head with newly pulled head
3. hg push release-candidate-repo

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial

```
[ui]
merge = internal:merge
```

With internal:merge, Mercurial inserts conflict markers showing the conflicting portions. You can pick one, the other, or neither.

```
$ cat hello.py
print 'hello world'
<<<<<<< local
print "charlie says: it is now Wed Apr 21 19:22:15 EDT 2010"
=======
print "baker says: it is now Wed Apr 21 19:20:34 EDT 2010"
>>>>>>> other
```

ReleaseManager just sent (or inform dev about incident) file with markers

Comment: From my POV - change workflow and exclude *dumb* RM is more power solution. RM will have enough work, but not *so stupid* as "merge code of others" - merges are **developers job**